# Access local variables defined inside another file

Tags: javascript

interface.js

```
((function(){
    var Person=function(){
    }
    .......
})();
```

implemention.js

```
((function(){
    //access local variables(Person) in interface.js
    Person.prototype.eat=function(){

    }
})();
```

load them:

```
function getScript(src) {
    document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' + ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
}

getScript("interface.js");
getScript("implemention.js");
```

As the code shown, I want to access the local variable "Person" defined in `interface.js` from `implemention.js`, it is not possible to access directly, so I tried to use the closure like this:

interface.js

```
((function(){
    ...
    var Person=function(){
    }
    window._load_implement=(function(){
        return function(impl){
            impl && impl();
            delete window._load_implement;
        }
    })();
})();
```

implemention.js

```
((function(){
    var imp=function(){
        Person.prototype.eat=....   
    }
    window._load_implement(imp);
})();
```

IMO, when the `imp` method run, the `Peson` and other variables should be closed which means should be accessed, but it does not work.

Is there anything wrong?

---

I post this question and tried to get an answer because I saw some similar usage, take the google map for example, the [`main.js`](https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/1/main.js) will be loaded, where all the map related objects like `Map` `Marker` and some util functions are defined there, then other google map modules like [`InfoWindow`](https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/1/infowindow.js) will be loaded when required, however the `infowindow.js` can all the util functions defined in the `main.js`.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they're in the same or different files. Variables that are local to a function cannot be accessed outside that function.

Comment: Javascript uses lexical scoping of variables. The scope of a local variable is only the functions that are _defined_ within the body of the function where the variable is declared. It doesn't include functions that are passed as parameters to these functions.

Comment: Is that means it is not possible for my requirement?

Comment: That's correct. You probably should look at OO programming to provide a way to make local variables accessible in an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use immediately invoked function expressions and add objects to the global namespace, you can explicitly add them to the window object or to another non-global object in the correct scope instead of defining objects as local variables inside the function:

```
(function(){
    window.Person = function(){
    }
    .......
})();
```

or

```
var Person = (function(){

})();
```

the latter is known as the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).